# Change default sitemap URL

Tags: url, redirect, sitemaps

Is there anyway to change the default sitemap url from:

```
http://mysite.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/category
```

to just:

```
http://mysite.com/sitemap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

odd_duck,you can do url rewrite mananger

which like
Request Path *`:sitemap`

Target Path *: `catalog/seo_sitemap/category`

Redirect: `no`

Comment: Thanks Amit. I have implemented this as seen here: [url=http://postimg.org/image/oaj4u6hin/][img]http://s11.postimg.org/oaj4u6hin/Screen_Shot_2014_09_11_at_08_53_05.jpg[/img][/url] and although I can now type `http://mysite.com/sitemap` to get to the sitemap, if i enter the `http://mysite.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/category` it doesn't force the url to change to `/sitemap`. Can this be done with the above?

Comment: htaccess redirection

Comment: actually ignore that sorry. I just created another url rewrite in admin, this time switching the 2 around and selecting 301 redirect

Comment: This won't change the links on the frontend, only redirect them.

Comment: busy now.Will reply later